# robots.txt and serving images from a separate domain

Tags: html, robots.txt

I'm trying to find out if a robots.txt file set on domain A will still apply to an image served from domain B, but actually displayed on domain A.

Example:

Somewhere on the page on `www.example.com`, there is an:

```
<img src="http://img.example.com/images/myimage.jpg" />`
```

In `www.example.com/robots.txt`, it says:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /images/
```

So when the spider hits www.example.com and sees the image being served from img.example.com, will it index it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

robots.txt only applies to the hostname it actually exists on.

Comment: As I suspected - a comment from another developer made me doubt myself!  Many thanks for the confirmation.